# Как открыть окно настроек?

Tags: android, settings

В приложении делаю проверку геолокации и если она выключена хочу запускать окно настроек (системное) которое отвечает за это, как это реализовать?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настройки девайса - обычное приложение. Все приложения запускаются интентами. Следовательно надо лишь узнать какой интент запустить. Можно поковырять доку, а можно вбить в гугл `android {НУЖНЫЙ ЭКРАН} intent`, т.е. в вашем случае -  [android location setting intent](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android%20location%20setting%20intent&oq=android%20location%20setting%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8732j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) и получить в первой строке выдачи [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16001582/3212712):

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Answer (score 4):

Лучше открывать не окно настроек, а именно диалог, который позволяет включить определение местоположения, не проходя на другие интенты. Как минимум это будет удобнее(очень удобнее) для пользователей, как максимум это будет правильнее в плане подхода к разработке. Да и коль Google дает такую возможность - игнорить просто расточительство.

```
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 2;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
SettingsClient mSettingsClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    ...
}

public void gpsRequest() {
        mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest).build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()); //запрос на обновление местоложения
                            //на случай, если пользователь дал добро
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        switch (((ApiException) e).getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                try {
                                    ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                    rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                    //на случай, если пользователь не дал добро
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ignored) {}
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        ...
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        ...
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

P.S. Данный код обновлен под новый формат [LocationSettingsRequest.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest.Builder) т.к. [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) **deprecated**.

P.P.S. Другими словами, данный код актуален для последней версии `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'` и отлично работает на Oreo и ниже (проверено).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]