# Почему mMap.getMyLocation() возвращает null?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, геолокация

Пытаюсь вытащить координаты из Google Map. В Location location кладу getMyLocation(). Но location после этого все равно остается null. Пермишены все прописаны. Чек пермишены тоже. Посооветовали прописать отдельные методы для проверки пермишенов - не помогло. Самое интересное то, что setMyLocationEnable(true) робит - синяя дефолтная точка на карте есть. Что делать?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker marker;

private Location location;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        return;
    };
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "координаты: широта (" + mLatitude + "), долгота (" + mLongitude + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().setInterval(1).setFastestInterval(1).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //здесь вы можете выбрать нужное время обновления местоположения и тип.
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()); //запрос на обновление местоположения
    };
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback); // чтоб батарею не жрал
}
```

}

```
app/
google-services.json
src/dogfood/google-services.json
src/release/google-services.json
...
```

Comment: А где и когда вы вызываете приведённый код? В каком методе/колбэке? Так же в коде не видны запросы к юзеру на выдачу разрешений (закомментированный код). В настройках приложения уровня девайса выданы эти разрешения?

Comment: да и получение положения - ассинхронная операция по логике.

Comment: обновил. закинул весь код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **По порядку:**

1. `getMyLocation()` - **deprecated** (забудьте о нем вообще).

[Изучите:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback)

```
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            if (location != null) Toast.makeText(this, "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

2. > Самое интересное то, что setMyLocationEnable(true) робит - синяя
   >   дефолтная точка на карте есть

Запустите на `API 23+` и ужаснетесь. А чтобы избежать ужаса сделайте следующее:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

3. [На крайняк](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location), а [именно](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java)
4. Изучите: [GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks), [GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) и добавьте еще два интерфейса в `implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

---

```
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
double mLatitude, mLongitude;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            return;
    };
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "координаты: широта (" + mLatitude + "), долгота (" + mLongitude + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().setInterval(1).setFastestInterval(1).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //здесь вы можете выбрать нужное время обновления местоположения и тип.
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()); //запрос на обновление местоположения
        };
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback); // чтоб батарею не жрал
}
```

---

**Обновите** `Google Play service` до 46

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Help -> Check for Updates...

---

**Gradle на уровне проекта:**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

**Gradle на уровне приложения:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

---

P.S. возможно [пригодится](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724869/205563) в дальнейшем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67032/discussion-on-answer-by-ifr0z--mmap-getmylocation--null).

Comment: @iFr0z `onLocationResult` вызывается после сворачивания и разворачивания приложения. После вызова циклится внутри `onLocationResult` (постоянно вызывается этот метод, видимо `Looper`'ом). Надо как-то остановить `myLooper`, чтобы такого не происходило?

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko это же callback, он необходим для того, чтобы постоянно получать свежие данные широты и долготы пользователя. Просто уберите тоасты, а переменные пусть обновляют значение, вдруг пригодятся. А от этого колбэка я и так указал то, что отписываться нужно в onPause.

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko а если не секрет, что Вы хотите то вообще собственно от своего приложения в конце? Я просто советовал бы вообще отказаться от гугл карт, google cloud и прочего гугловского, т.к. в итоге это будет стоить денюшек. Особенно, если проект бесплатный. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899812/Какие-есть-ограничения-по-использованию-googlemap-и-directions?noredirect=1#comment1474516_899812

Comment: @iFr0z я хочу сразу после запуска переместиться в своё местоположение. Как это сделать?