# Какие есть ограничения по использованию googlemap и directions

Tags: java, android, google-maps

На днях начали в андроид программу внедрять гугл карту и сделать так чтобы рисовались маршруты.Но через какое то время в логах выходит надпись что лимит превышен(квота),и маршрут перестает появляться .Я в гугл консоли вроде все активировал,перевел аккаунт на платный.Но ошибка все время выходит и маршрут не рисуется.Не появиться ли такая ситуация с картой когда будут люди начнут пользоваться программой? Вообще какие условия сейчас с гугл картой может кто знает?Много чего прочитал но так и ничего нормального не нашел.И еще как включить биллинг?возможно у меня из за него не работает маршрут.Прочитал тарифы в платном режиме ,цены очень высокие.Если использовать только карту и наносить на него маркеры это будет бесплатно? Какие лимиты есть(максимальные) чтоб бесплатно пользоваться,нам нужна карта а в место обьектов будут просто маркеры  и маршрут. Много вопросов задал..помогите пожалуйста.Времени не хватает  чтоб самому разобраться.

Comment: Вкратце, google maps v2 теперь входит в google cloud platform, и если оплачивать все это дело, то там. Прайс - https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/. Цены очень высокие. 1 маршрут в день вроде, если бесплатно. Вот отличная статья на habr'e https://habr.com/post/417715/ для введения в курс дела на данный момент и возможные решения, аналоги. Вроде как просто карта с маркерами - это бесплатно (пока ещё), но вот маршрут уже дело платное. P.S. Я например перебрался на YMK 3.1.1 https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/quickstart-docpage/ из-за этого.

Comment: @iFr0z спасибо большое.Похоже тоже будем использовать YandexMK.