# Стандартное activity с Google maps вылетает

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Все, что я сделал - это создал `google maps activity` и заменил `api-key` по [инструкции](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#get-key).

*При отключенном интернете открывается приложение, а в нем непрогруженная карта (ничего удивительного - интернета нет). Но при запуске приложения c интернетом оно вылетает сразу же.*

*Проблема возникает где-то во время соединения с интернетом (другие стандартные приложения типа хрома и карт в эмуляторе работают без вылетов и при включенном и при выключенном эмуляторе).*

*Ещё раз повторю, что поменял только ключ апи и не производил больше никаких манипуляций, то есть при запуске с подключенным интернетом должно было запуститься приложение с маркером около Сиднея, однако оно **вылетает**.*

В чем может быть проблема?

---

**UPD1**

Обнаружил потенциальный `NullPointerException`:

[image: probably nullPointerException]

---

**UPD2**

Логи:

```
2018-12-16 20:44:30.371 17729-17729/com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm E/th1ng.gps_alar: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
2018-12-16 20:44:30.854 1872-2014/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-16 20:44:31.413 17729-17783/com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2018-12-16 20:44:31.413 17729-17783/com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2018-12-16 20:44:31.416 1872-1878/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-16 20:44:31.951 17729-17757/com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
    Process: com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm, PID: 17729
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at ep.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):3)
        at eo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):4)
        at eq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):55)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):11)
        at dx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):17)
        at dx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):65)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/app_chimera/m/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):25)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at ep.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):3) 
        at eo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):4) 
        at eq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):55) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):11) 
        at dx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):17) 
        at dx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):65) 
2018-12-16 20:44:32.067 1594-1594/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/17729/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2018-12-16 20:44:32.103 1930-2018/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '6f23002 com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm/com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm.MapsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-12-16 20:44:32.943 1872-1877/? E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (4 threads) starved for 264 ms
2018-12-16 20:44:52.849 1930-2844/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-16 20:44:56.811 1798-1798/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2018-12-16 20:45:03.198 1704-1757/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2018-12-16 20:45:52.921 1930-2844/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-16 20:45:56.812 1798-1798/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2018-12-16 20:46:03.201 1704-1757/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
```

---

**UPD3**

Код build.gradle (приложение):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Код build.gradle (проект)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.s0meth1ng.gps_alarm">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: На какой версии OC Android тестировали? Какие либы использовали? последние ли они?

Comment: @iFr0z в логе только время компиляции. Специально перезапустил студию чтобы весь лог от запуска студии до вылета приложения был. Добавил его в вопрос.

Comment: @iFr0z Nexus 5x API 28 Android 9.0 (Google APIs). Не знаю, что использовал - запускаю стандартный проект, андроид студия установлена около недели назад, т.е., как я полагаю, всё должно быть последним при создании шаблона.

Comment: Проверьте мой ответ, данный тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729995/205563 Там указан весь код, который актуален и сейчас, но только либы используйте последних версий. Должно помочь. Карта с местоположением пользователя и меткой будет отображаться на всех ОС Андроид, и не будет вылетать приложение с NPE.

Comment: @Simon Gerasimenko где логи в вопросе , о которых вы пишете?

Comment: @Романыч их зачем-то удалил модератор, но относительно вылетов в них все равно ничего нет

Comment: Потому что лог сборки это не то :(

Comment: Дело в том, что данный код, который Вы выложили картинкой, не доведён до рабочего состояния почему-то.

Comment: @iFr0z вы имеете ввиду не доведен мной? Откуда взять логи, которые вы хотите посмотреть?

Comment: Нет, нет, дело в примере, который вшит, он старый. Откройте вкладку в нижней панели “logcat” а там выберете тип, аля “verbose” или “error” напрямую. Запустите проект, и выложите то, что красным будет написано.

Comment: @iFr0z добавил в вопрос. Видимо данные об ошибке после FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8. Вроде что-то с протоколом, но могу ошибаться

Comment: @Романыч добавил логи, можете посмотреть. С условием на "поймать nullPointerException" тоже вылетает

Comment: А скиньте весь код build.gradle уровней приложения и проекта и manifest

Comment: @iFr0z добавил, upd3

Comment: а добавьте ка в `manifest` следующее: `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`, а ещё в тэге `application` добавьте `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `Android 6.0` удалена поддержка `Apache HTTP`-клиента. Начиная с `Android 9.0`, библиотека удаляется из `bootclasspath` и более не доступна для приложений по умолчанию.‎[1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p)

‎Чтобы продолжить использование `Apache HTTP`-клиент для `Android 9.0` и выше нужно добавить в `manifest` следующее: [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779)

```
<application
    ...>

    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

    ...
</application>
```

> **Примечание**:‎‎ ‎‎`«false»‎‎` атрибут требуется
>   для приложений, которые имеют минимальный `SDK 23` или ниже, потому что
>   на устройствах с `API` уровнем ниже, чем `24`, ‎‎`org.apache.http.legacy‎‎`
>   библиотека не доступна. [1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p)

---

Источники: [1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p), [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779)

Comment: Этот ответ сработал. Непосредственно в `application` ничего не добавлял, как Вы писали в комментарии к вопросу. Можно кратко суть ответа? Что я добавил? Что это за библиотека? Почему без неё не работало? Спасибо за решение

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
А если так?



SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (supportMapFragment != null) {
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


 @Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.mMap = googleMap;


if (mMap != null) {

        mMap.addMarker(......);
    }

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15);
    mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

где логи о которых вы пишете `NullPointerException:`\

где разметка, гадаем на кофейной гуще?

Comment: Про логи ответил вам на комментарий, разметка и все остальное кроме апи - стандартные как сразу после создания google maps activity