# Android приложение с геоданными

Tags: android, gps

У меня такой вопрос:
С кодом вроде все впорядке, приложение работает когда включено "местоположение" на телефоне. Но когда выключено то ничего не происходит.
Я думаю что можно каким-то программным образом запускать без ведома пользователя эти геоданные, и без включения самих геоданных на телефоне (надеюсь понятно объяснил:) ).
Как бы, в том же приложении Gismeteo есть "использовать GPS" , соответственно для этого приложения включается данная фича. (при этом телефон отображает что GPS выключен, и видимо приложение само по себе его использует).

Пожалуйста, подскажите как это реализовать (желательно с примером (кодом)).

Comment: там используют примерное местоположение на основе вышек мобильной сети

Comment: вот например есть такой сервис https://opencellid.org/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724869/205563